# Can Server sent events (sse) work with AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, server-sent-events

Is there a way to make sse (server sent events) work using Cloudfront?

I know they announced websockets support few years ago but I can not find any reference or cases related to using sse communication through Cloudfront.

I did a test and the client response ends with 504 Gateway Time-out after a minute approx.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use SSE (Server-Sent Events) with CloudFront.

There are many different ways to implement your API behind CloudFront. So, in some cases, there could be limitations. But let me describe one standard and straightforward way you could set up your application that is tested to work with SSE.

Let's say you have an EC2 instance (at least one) that is behind an ALB (Application Load Balancer). Even if you don't need more than one EC2 instance, you might need an ALB in order to use HTTPS. Even though you will need to import your TLS/SSL certificate into your CloudFront [Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-working-with.html), you will also need your API to be accessible (by CloudFront itself) via HTTPS (don't forget it could be located in another continent).

In CloudFront you can create a Distribution with an [Origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_Origin.html) that basically maps `https://yourapp.com/api` to that ALB. Note that CloudFront also allows you to forward traffic to a different (sub)domain if that's where your API/ALB is (that setup I've also tested successfully).

Answer (score -1):

Websockets works with AWS API Gateway. You can use AppSync (GraphQL) Subscriptions also. CloudFront can’t send anything himself.

Comment: I know there are alternatives but this doesn't answer the question

Comment: As I said, CloudFront don’t support Server Side events

Answer (score -1):

AWS resources are linked with event bridge (Basically async way to trigger an event) and its stateless so it is not possible. The only way is you have to deploy your app in some sort of web container using which you can achieve your expected behaviour.
Another way is you can use AWS API Gateways's websocket open the connection (Full duplex) and back and forth transafer what ever data you want.